# How to create a custom layer using the keras Functional API, that supports masking?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, masking

I want to use the Functional API to create a custom *layer* that supports masking, meaning that it propagates a mask on the input tensor so that the output is also masked.

There are explicit instructions in the Keras guide for doing this for a custom layer using subclassing. Here is a trivial example of a custom layer which supports masking:

```
import tensorflow as tf


class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, multiplier=2.0):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
        self.multiplier = multiplier
        self.supports_masking = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs * self.multiplier
```

When we pass the tensor `x_emb` which has a mask we see it get propogated:

```
raw_inputs = [
    [711, 632, 71],
    [73, 8, 3215, 55, 927],
    [83, 91, 1, 645, 1253, 927],
]

padded_inputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    raw_inputs, padding="post"
)

embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(5000, 16, mask_zero=True)
x_emb = embedding(padded_inputs)

custom_layer = CustomLayer()
output1 = custom_layer(x_emb)
print(output1._keras_mask)
```

The sequential API automatically supports masking (assuming all of its constituent layers do). For example:

```
sequential_layer = tf.keras.Sequential([
    custom_layer,
    custom_layer
])
output2 = sequential_layer(x_emb)
print(output2._keras_mask)
```

My question is how to make the functional API also support masking, if possible? By default it does not:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
outputs = custom_layer(inputs)
functional_layer = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
output3 = functional_layer(x_emb)
print(output3._keras_layer)

## AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_keras_layer'
```

**Edit**: There is no issue here. I made an embarrasing type writing `_keras_layer` instead of `_keras_mask`.

Comment: `output3._keras_layer`? `output3._keras_mask` should output something as same as `output1._keras_mask` and `output2._keras_mask`

Comment: No, that's the whole point of my question. The mask is not propagated to `output3` so it has no `_keras_layer` attribute.

Comment: I am with @Mr.ForExample , I think you are confusing `_keras_layer ` with `_keras_mask`. I have run it and `output3._keras_mask` gives no error, while `_keras_layer` gives error in all three

Comment: Yes, I didn't read @Mr.ForExample 's comment carefully, on top of the `_keras_layer` typo.

Comment: There is no issue. My bad @BCJuan, thanks for your help. I voted to close this.